# Filtering items which are contained in sample string

Tags: java, hamcrest, lambdaj

I want to use Lambdaj and hamcrest matchers to simply check if sample string contains at least one of the list's item.

```
private static List<String> FIELDS=Arrays.asList("one","two","three","four");

String myString="This string may contain 'one' word or 'two' word";
boolean stringContainsItem=filter(Matchers.containsString(myString),FIELDS).isEmpty();
```

but the matcher is incorrect.
I need in that place some inverted Matcher, which check if myString contains lists's item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own matcher:

```
private static List<String> FIELDS=Arrays.asList("one","two","three","four");

String myString="This string may contain 'one' word or 'two' word";
boolean stringDoesNotContainItem=filter(createIsInStringMatcher(myString),FIELDS).isEmpty();
```

with:

```
private TypeSafeMatcher<String> createIsInStringMatcher(final String string) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<String>() {

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(String item) {
            return string.indexOf(item) >= 0;
        }
    };
}
```

EDIT:  There is also another Lambdaj method `exists` which allows to write this in a more compact way:

```
List<String> FIELDS = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four");

String myString = "This string may contain 'one' word or 'two' word";
boolean stringContainsItem = Lambda.exists(FIELDS, createIsInStringMatcher(myString));
```